# GCC: why a -Wformat warning for this fprintf?

Tags: c, gcc, types, warnings, printf

We cleaned up a large number of warnings. In several cases, we replaced %s with %d. Everything seemed OK until we realized that the generated code wouldn't compile - strings had been replaced by numbers.

**NOTE:** I had the wrong revision checked out when I did the copy&paste. The fprintf string has been edited!

**GCC output**

> fedex_plus/classes.c:2425:3: warning: format **‘%s’** expects argument of type **‘char *’**, but argument 3 has type **‘int’** [-Wformat]

**lines 2424 and 2425:**

```
fprintf(file, "\n//\t%s_ptr create_TIE();\n\tIDL_Application_instance_ptr create_TIE();\n", 
    ENTITYget_CORBAname(entity));
```

**function ENTITYget_CORBAname:**

```
const char *
ENTITYget_CORBAname (Entity ent)
{
    static char newname [BUFSIZ];
    strcpy( newname, ENTITYget_name(ent) );
    newname[0] = ToUpper (newname [0]);
    return newname;
}
```

Comment: ouch for `strcpy`... This is way more serious than printing a random number here or there. You should consider `strncpy` instead.

Comment: @Alexandre: Thanks for that. We're going to run cppcheck on it at some point; I assume that this type of problem will be caught. Right now we're trying to get rid of gcc warnings to see if they fix any of the bugs we know of.  The code is so old that the documentation explains in detail how to use the mouse (https://github.com/mpictor/StepClassLibrary/wiki/dataprobe.1)

Comment: omg... Also good luck with the 3000+ line source file !

Comment: @Alexandre: 5350 lines is better than the 310089 lines in one of the .cc files it generates for STEP AP214! The ESA developed a similar tool they haven't released, and there are insanely expensive commercial tools - unfortunately, this is the only open source tool of its kind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My bet is that no declaration of `ENTITYget_CORBAname` is available at the `fprintf` spot. Should this be the case, it defaults to the implicit signature:

```
int ENTITYget_CORBAname(...);
```

hence the warning about the result type being an `int`.

Check your code with `-Wimplicit` (implied by `-Wall`), or try to put

```
const char *ENTITYget_CORBAname (Entity ent);
```

before the `fprintf` line and check if the warning disappears. If it does, then you're likely missing a header.

Comment: You found it!

fedex_plus/classes.c:2425:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ENTITYget_CORBAname’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print a pointer value, use `%p`, if you want to print the string returned from the function, use `%s`. Don't use `%d` in any of this cases. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: Sorry, had the wrong revision checked out when I did the copypasta. The code originally had %s, and gcc complained about that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `ENTITY_GETCorbaName()` returns a string, so if you want to print that, use `%s`. If you want to print it as pointer, use `%p`.

Comment: Sorry, had the wrong revision checked out when I did the copypasta. The code originally had %s, and gcc complained about that.

Comment: Hmmm... if ENTITYget_CORBAname returns a string (well, char*) then I wonder why you get the error. IME, compilers seldom make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

use `%s` in your `printf` to print that string or use `%p` in your `printf` to show pointer value you can also use `%lld` to prints its value